# Clustering standard errors for difference in difference

Tags: bootstrap, difference-in-difference, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error, cluster-sample

I am running a difference in difference to examine the effect of a merger on petrol prices. I am looking to see whether the prices of company A have increased due to a merger with company B.

Local petrol markets are a 2km radius around a station of company A. My treatment group (Affected) is petrol stations of company A which contain a petrol station of company B within 2km. The control group (Unaffected) is petrol stations of company A which do not contain a petrol station of company B within 2km.
Pre and Post refers to pre and post the merger of these two companies.

I have 15 months of daily, station-level petrol price data to test this hypothesis. I am analysing the full population rather than a sample. Population size is 17000 for Affected and 45000 for Unaffected.

My difference in difference is standard. $Prices = \beta_0*Affected + \beta_1*Post + \beta_2*(Affected*Post)$.

My results are positive and statistically significant at the 1% level. However I have been reading about clustering and whether this would change my results.

My questions:

- Do I need to cluster to get accurate standard errors?
- If so, at which level? Other papers I've read have been able to break their regressor down into local markets or regions and cluster them at that level, but I only have the local markets that I defined above. Should I contrive a few geographical regions to cluster with?
- I've read another paper that uses bootstrapping to overcome a similar problem. Is this necessary?

Comment: It's worth thinking about what the experimental treatment is and how it is being applied. Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems like you have something like a "within-subjects" design, where the experimental treatment is "merger * proximity" and the "subject" is company A. There are two ways to operationalize this, I think:
Company -> Treatment -> Station, which presumes a fixed treatment effect, or
Company -> Treatment -> Company x Treatment -> Station, which has an interaction which says "different companies may have different effects."

Comment: The decision to cluster depends entirely on the structure of the experiment and nothing else, to answer your first two questions.

Comment: @rishi-k if all the stations in the analysis are owned by the same company then they should have the same treatment effect each.

Comment: In which case the fixed effect model is acceptable and you do not have to cluster standard errors. It sounds like you're just trying to comment on the effect the merger had on the gas prices of this company's stations, and not the effects of mergers in general, right?

Comment: yes thats correct. to clarify, do you mean I should run a separate fixed effects model, or the current diff-in-diff is appropriate?

Comment: What you are doing now is appropriate. If you had multiple companies and wanted to talk about the effects of mergers in general, you'd want to cluster at the "company" level, but if you are just trying to talk about this merger's effect on this company, your model seems fine to me.

Comment: thank you @rishi-